# Navigation Bar and Sliding Tab xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to make a `Navigation Bar` and `Sliding Tab` with `Fragments` in `xamarin` android. That when you open its `Drawer` and click a Text inside its drawer it will open a new layout or Fragment. Same in Sliding Tab.

Any Tutorials or File that i can debug. I really want to Learn.

A drawer Like this one:

[image: https://blog.xamarin.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/NavigationDrawer-595x1024.png]

A Sliding Tab like this:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/rhRXjLIl.png]

I'm Pretty new so i would really appreciate the help.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Easiest way to do it would be like this :

Navigation Drawer:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-left-drawer-layout/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-android-navigation-drawer-layout-using-support-design/

Sliding tab :

http://camposha.info/source/xamarin-android-swipe-tabs-viewpager-fragments-images-actionbartabs/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-sliding-tab-layout-interface-using-xamarin-android-using-visual-studio/

The code is in xamarin so it would be an easy implementation for you!
Goodluck!